# How to reset observable after placing the order in eCommerce site in angular8?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

In my `angular8` ecommerce app i have a child `component` named `shoppingWidget` which is in parent component named 'header'. In  `shoppingWidget` i am displaying `cart` items `count` on `icon`. For this i have a `cart.service.ts` in which i have a `function` like this

```
public getItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
  const itemsStream = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(products);
    observer.complete();
  });
  return <Observable<CartItem[]>>itemsStream;
}
```

with the help of this i am first getting cart items in my parent component`(header)` like this

```
  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {
    this.cartService.getItems().subscribe(shoppingCartItems => this.shoppingCartItems = shoppingCartItems);

  }
```

and then pasing `this.shoppingCartItems` in my child component `shoppingWidget` like this

```
<div class="main-menu-wrapper-2" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
     <mat-toolbar class="top-navbar top menu">
        <app-shopping-widgets [shoppingCartItems]="shoppingCartItems"></app-shopping-widgets>
     </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

Now cart is working perfectly. But the problem is that when used is finished with placing order on website so i have to reset that `count` which is displaying on the cart and i want to set that count again to `0`.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: where is `products`  in `observer.next(products)` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this bit here:

```
public getItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
  const itemsStream = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(products);
    observer.complete();
  });
  return <Observable<CartItem[]>>itemsStream;
}
```

doesn't really make much sense as an observable. you'd accomplish the same thing with `return of(products)` but that's equally not useful for a stream you can control. you need a subject.

```
private itemsSource = new BehaviorSubject(products);

public getItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
  return this.itemsSource.asObservable(); // this doesn't complete, must unsubscribe
}

public resetItems() {
  this.itemsSource.next([]);
}
```

using the subject lets you control the observable, and you need to not complete that observable to continue receiving updates about it.